# Difference between ctime 1 and ctime +1 in find command

Tags: find

If I run the following command:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -type f -ctime +1
```

I get no results back, whereas if i run:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -type f -ctime 1
```

I get results.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That means all the jar files in the directory had status changes less than 48 hours ago.

#### Detailed explanation

According to the `find` man page,

```
-ctime n
    File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago.
```

And ...

```
When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was 
last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, 
a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.
```

And elsewhere ...

```
+n for greater than n
```

Therefore `-ctime +1` means the file status must have changed at least 48 hours ago.